# Windows won't load and neither will Ubuntu after removing Ubuntu partitions

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm using Windows 8.1. I deleted two of the Linux partitions from Windows disc manager. However, two of them still remained that wouldn't let me delete (they were blank). I ignored them, and expanded the Windows partition.

Then, I was preparing to do a Windows recovery disc option, but then on accident I pressed the power button on my computer. Everything shut down. So, I just went through with what I was going to do anyway, and put the Windows recovery disc media in. I did the bootrec stuff, and still no luck.

When I restarted, all that showed up was a gnu grub menu with a weird text based console. I'd like to avoid reinstalling Windows, as I have may important files on there. However, if I did, it wouldn't be the end of the world, but I'd rather make this a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you did is screwed up the bootloader.  You need a standalone bootloader CD, which you can get an image of here: http://www.supergrubdisk.org

Comment: That didn't work, it is showing a weird grub console when u boot from usb

Comment: Define weird please?